# How would you separate sodium chloride and copper sulfate?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, separation-techniques

I've tried dissolving both compounds in water and evaporating the mixture, but this leaves a combination of brown and green crystals. Is there was any way to cleanly separate both compounds? Any advice would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: They are not there anymore. You can't separate them without chemically transforming at least some of the ions involved. Typically, when you separate a mixture, you need just one of the components. Which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a solution of sodium chloride $\ce{(NaCl)}$ and copper sulfate ($\ce{CuSO4}$), in a beaker/conical flask. First, you treat this mixture with excess **potassium ferrocyanide** $(\ce{K_4[Fe(CN)_6]})$. Due to this addition, **a choclate brown precipitate of $\ce{Cu_2[Fe(CN)_6]}$ (cupric ferrocyanide) is formed** while the $\ce{NaCl}$ remain unreacted.

$$\ce{CuSO_4 + K_4[Fe(CN)_6] -> Cu_2[Fe(CN)_6](ppt) + K_2SO_4}$$

Then you filter the solution, and you will have the precipitate separated from the solution, which now only contains $\ce{NaCl}$. Now take the cupric ferrocyanide and treat with excess $\ce{NH_4OH}$, and it will form a **precipitate of cupric hydroxide $(\ce{Cu(OH)_2})$**.

Again, filter the precipitate and treat the compound with a **concentrated solution of sulfuric acid ($\ce{H_2SO_4}$)**. With this, you will get back original copper sulfate, and now, it is seperated from $\ce{NaCl}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suspected that separating this mixture would require a little more than physical separation techniques. Very informative.